# Appropriate method signature with optional parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a class with a constructor that looks like the following

```
class SomeClass():

  def __init__(self, aaa, bbb, ccc)
```

If either only aaa and bbb or ccc are required, what would be the most appropriate method signature?

Is the following method signature appropriate in this case?

```
def __init__(self, aaa=None, bbb=None, ccc=None)
```

Comment: Are all three allowed? If not, I might consider `__init__(self, x)`, where `x` must be either a *tuple* `(aaa, bbb)` or a single element `ccc` (to be checked inside the method).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That sounds more appropriate in this case

Comment: A type hint like `__init__(self, x : Union[Tuple[atype, btype], ctype])` would help as well (for documentation, using whatever types `atype`, `btype`, and `ctype` are appropriate).

Comment: I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the signature shown in your question used in popular Python libraries like [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), but their usage was different: instead of requiring **precisely one** of the options `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, that particular function supported **each** argument to be specified or unspecified, independently of one another.

For your case, I'd probably do something like this:

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, option, **kwargs):
        # implementation here
```

and the usage might look like any of these:

```
SomeClass('aaa')
SomeClass('bbb', some_b_specific_option='some other value')
SomeClass(option='ccc')
```